# CLion: force full sync in remote mode

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, jetbrains-ide

While using full remote mode targeting Debian OS I noticed local source files differ from remote sources. Rebuild command is invoking cmake on remote dir containing outdated source files.

Is there command to do full sync? Any other method to troubleshoot sync issues? How can I check remote dir for automatic sync is the same as remote dir that remote cmake uses?